# Scanner only reading first set of input

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

This is a code I have developed to separate inputs by the block (when a space is reached):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Single {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Three Numbers:");
        String numbers = in.next();
        int length = numbers.length();
        System.out.println(length);
        int sub = length - length;
        System.out.println(sub);
        System.out.println(getNumber(numbers, length, sub));
        System.out.println(getNumber(numbers, length, sub));
        System.out.println(getNumber(numbers, length, sub));
    }
    public static double getNumber(String numbers, int length, int sub){
        boolean gotNumber = false;
        String currentString = null;
        while (gotNumber == false){
            if (numbers.substring(sub, sub + 1) == " "){
                sub = sub + 1;
                gotNumber = true;
            } else {
                currentString = currentString + numbers.substring(sub, sub);
                sub = sub + 1;
            }
        }
        return Double.parseDouble(currentString);
    }
}
```

However, it only reads the first set for the string, and ignores the rest.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here. You should replace this line

```
String numbers = in.next();
```

with this line

```
String numbers = in.nextLine();
```

because, next() can read the input only till the first `space` while nextLine() can read input till the `newline` character. For more info check [this link](http://jesterjava.blogspot.com/2012/09/difference-between-next-and-nextline.html).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you are only calling in.next() once. If you want to have it process the input over and over again you want a loop until you don't have any more input.

```
while (in.hasNext()) {
    //do number processing in here
}
```

Hope this helps!